# Disable slideDown/Up on links inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basicllay i have a div with a class called .li-level-1, and inside that i have differnt ul's with lists. i Have it set up so when you click on a li-level-1 div displays the ul's and li's inside that div by animating a drop down and when you click on the next one it closes the one previously opened and slidesDown the next one.

the only thing is the a links that are inside the div's seem to trigger the slideUp/Down on level-1 and animation as well.

any Suggestions?

```
$('.sitemap_page .li-level-1').each(function(){
    $(this).find('ul.ul-level-2').hide();
    $(this).click(function(){
        var this_list = $(this);
        this_list.parent().find('.open').each(function(){
            $(this).slideUp(function(){
                this_list.find('ul.ul-level-2').addClass("open").slideDown();
            }).removeClass('open');
        });
        if(this_list.find('ul.ul-level-2.open').length == 0) {
            this_list.find('ul.ul-level-2').addClass("open").slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.bubbles): the `click` event raised on the `<a>` elements bubble up to their containing `<div>` and cause your event handler to execute.

One way to work around that problem would be to use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to determine the event's origin, and only perform the sliding animations if the event did not originate on a link:

```
$(this).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is("a")) {
        var this_list = $(this);
        this_list.parent().find('.open').each(function() {
            $(this).slideUp(function() {
                this_list.find('ul.ul-level-2').addClass("open").slideDown();
            }).removeClass('open');
        });
        if (this_list.find('ul.ul-level-2.open').length == 0) {
            this_list.find('ul.ul-level-2').addClass("open").slideDown();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with event bubbling as sugested by Frederic. The other possible solution is to divide your div into title and content divs. Hold data in content and check click on title (not on the parent list). This means rebuilding the handler but the code will be clearer and it won't depend on `event.target`.